# Min/Max Values Across Multiple Sublists within a Dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I'm working on a program that will read a .txt file of NBA team names with fives statistics for each team into a dictionary.  I was able to read the file into a dictionary with the correct key-value pairs, but I can't figure out how to return a table of minimum, maximum, and average values for each statistic across all teams.  I've looked at other questions on the site, but I can't find anything pertaining to a key with multiple values per entry in the dictionary.  Here's what the dictionary looks like for a few of the entries:

```
 {'Golden State Warriors':[113.5, 107.5, 43.5, 0.503, 8.0], 'Houston Rockets':[112.4, 103.9, 43.5, 0.46, 8.5], ... : ...}
```

I need to make a table that displays the min, max, and average of each statistic across all entries:

```
      PPG     PPAG     RPG     FG     SPG
 MIN
 MAX
 AVG
```

I can do this kind of stuff with the statistics in the form of a list, but whenever I try to write lists into a dictionary, I get a TypeError.  Would greatly appreciate suggestions, I've been stuck on this for hours.

Also, IMPORTANT NOTE:  I cannot use lambda for this task, I am working on this for a project and my options are for loops, while loops, and the basic list functions and dictionary methods.

Comment: Your dictionnary seem weird, it's not a json format (number with string after, miss comma ...).

Comment: That was a typo!  Strings after the numbers were to indicate the type of statistic.  I can't use import json, either.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following code should do the computation of the stas:

```
from statistics import mean
lists = list(dic.values())
output = {'MIN':[], 'MAX':[], 'AVG':[]}

for i in range(0, len(lists[0])):
    output['MIN'].append(min(col[i] for col in lists))
    output['MAX'].append(max(col[i] for col in lists))
    output['AVG'].append(mean(col[i] for col in lists))
```

To print the results as a table, you may do the following:

```
print("\tPPG\tPPAG\tRPG\tFG\tSPG")
for stats in output:
    print(stats, end='\t')
    for i in range(0, cols):
       print(round(output[stats][i], 3), end='\t')
    print()
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

As long as all the data for each team is in the same order in the dictionary this will work well for your purpose. I started by forming a list containing the dictionary values which are also lists. Then you can zip the sub lists together, this has the handy feature of grouping all the same indices in the lists together. Now we can call max, min, and mean on each zip'd stat! If you can not import the 'statistics' module a list comp would also be an easy one liner.

```
from statistics import mean
stats = {'Golden State Warriors':[113.5, 107.5, 43.5, 0.503, 8.0], 'Houston Rockets':[112.4, 103.9, 43.5, 0.46, 8.5]}
values = [*zip(*stats.values())]
for value in values:
    print("max: {}\nmin: {}\nmean: {:0.3f} \n".format(max(value), min(value), mean(value)))
```

EDIT: take note that if you try to zip lists together that are not the same length it will zip by the shortest list. This behavior can be corrected by using the itertools izip_longest and providing a default value.